# Negative charge of orbit

Tags: electrons

Why is the energy of orbit (of electron) negative. Explain.
Electrons are negatively charged and electrons revolve round the nucleus in the orbit hence the orbit is negatively charged but what are the proves for electron's negative charge.

Comment: The negative energy of orbitals has nothing to do with the negative charge of electrons. You could have an antimatter world in which a positron orbits an antiproton and the energy of the positron would still be negative. It has to do with the solution of the Schrodinger equation which shows that normalisable eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian correspond to negative energy eigenvalues (specifically, orbitals are bound states in a Coulomb potential which goes to 0 at infinity, so their energies are negative).

Answer (score 1):

Negative energy of a system means lower energy than a set zero energy level. We set the zero level for an electron-nucleus pair to the energy of independent particles (electron and nucleus are infinite distance). It is just a convention that makes calculation easy, but you could choose the zero anywhere.

If the energy is lower than that (i.e. negative), the particles are interacting with each other and they don't have enough kinetic energy to split apart. If they have positive energy, it means the electron has enough kinetic energy to just fly away from the nucleus wherever it want. When it flies away, it is not an atom anymore. This happens in plasma or when you hit the atoms with some high energy (ionizing) radiation.